# Bitbucket pipeline deploy ignores vendor folder with ftp upload

Tags: php, deployment, composer-php, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy PHP project using bitbucket pipeline. With this code:

```
init: # -- First time init
  - step:
      name: build
      image: php:7.1.1
      caches:
        - composer
      script:
        - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
        - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
        - composer install
        - vendor/bin/phpunit
      artifacts: # defining vendor/ as an artifact
        - vendor/**
  - step:
      image: samueldebruyn/debian-git
      name: deployment
      script:
        - apt-get update
        - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
        - git ftp init -u "$FTP_DEV_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_DEV_PASSWORD" ftp://$FTP_DEV_HOST/$FTP_DEV_FOLDER
```

But it ignores the vendor folder. I have assumed, that artifacts will add this folder to deploy too.

What is wrong or what can I do better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you probably have a `.gitignore` which includes the `vendor` directory. The artifacts are in fact passed to the next step by bitbucket but are ignored by git-ftp. In order to upload these files with git-ftp you need to create a file called `.git-ftp-include` where you will need to add the following line: `!vendor/`. The `!` is required as stated in the [docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/git-ftp.1.html):

> The  .git-ftp-include  file  specifies  intentionally  untracked files that Git-ftp should
>          upload.  If you have a file that should always be uploaded, add a line  beginning  with  !
>          followed  by the file's name.

Comment: Save my days...You are such a champ.. Thank you so much